# State Space Model for SARIMA

Tags: time-series, arima, state-space-models

**Objective:**

I wanted to find the state space model for $SARIMA(3,2,1)(2,1,1)_5$. I simplified the expression and obtained the following:

- B is backshift operator
- $w_t$ is white noise

**Equation:**

$(1-\phi_1 B - \phi_2 B - \phi_3 B)(1-\Phi_1 B^5-\Phi_2 B^{10})(x_t - x_{t-5} -2x_{t-1}+2x_{t-6}+x_{t-2}-x_{t-7})=w_t(1+\theta_1 B)(1+\Theta_1 B^5)$

**Problem:**

I don't understand how this can be translated in state space, like where does the $\Theta$ and $\Phi$ terms go in the matrix.

**Understanding:**

I understand that AR(p,q) which is of the following form:

$$x_t = \phi_1 x_t −1 + · · · + \phi_p x_{t-p} + \theta_1 w_{t-1} + · · · + \theta_{q} w_{t-q} + w_t$$

can be written as the following state space model

- $k$ is max(p,q+1)

$x_t$ = [1 0 .... 0 ] $r_t$

$r_t$   $\mathbf = \left[\begin{array}
{rrr}
\phi_1 & 1 & 0 ... & 0 \\
\phi_2 & 0 & 1 ... & 0 \\
. & . & ... & 0 \\
\phi_k & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
r_{t-1} + w_t$  $\mathbf * \left[\begin{array}
{rrr}
1 \\
\theta_1 \\
.\\
.\\
\theta_{k-1}
\end{array}\right]$